# Add trailing zeros in money and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, currency

I want to know how to add trailing zeros in time and cash.

I have this:

> 0h1  0.0 $

but I want to get it like this:

> 0h01 0.00 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For currency, use [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency). It should be something like

> number_to_currency(1.4, format: "%n %u")

For time, use [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Answer (score 3):

What you want here is:

```
'%.2f' % your_thing
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some helper methods for numbers in Rails. Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html (especially number_with_precision might be interesting in your case)

Comment: there are something like this whose i can use it in models ? because this is only useable with views ..

Comment: you could `include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` in your model